# What is wrong with my translator? (Python)

Tags: python, syntax-error

I made a translator using python here is the code:

```
def answer(plaintext):
    words = {"a":100000,"b":110000,"c":100100,"d":100110,"e":100010,"f":110100,"g":110110,"h":110010,"i":010100"j":010110,"k":101000,"l":111000,"m":101100,"n":101110,"o"101010:,"p":111100,"q":111110,"r":111010,"s":011100,"t":011110,"u":101001,"v":111001,"w":010111,"x":010111,"y":101011,"z":101011}
input = "j, o, s, e"
inputList = input.split(',')
for word in inputList:
    print words[word]
```

The syntax error is on line 2.

Comment: Please put the code into a code block for better readability

Comment: It has an error when I try putting it in a code block

Comment: You're missing a colon between "o" and 101010 and a comma between 010100 and "j"

Comment: You're missing a comma before `j` and also your `o` entry needs a colon between the key and value and has an extraneous colon after the value. All of which you could have seen by looking.

Comment: That too.  Those should probably all be strings.

Comment: @Alan sure, but I just noticed user has python2, my bad

Comment: Integers starting with 0 in Python 2 are interpreted as octal numbers, you should make the values be strings instead

Comment: and don't use `input` as a variable name - there is a builtin function of the same name.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `answer()` function? You never call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want something like:

```
def answer(plaintext):
    words = {"a":'100000',"b":'110000',"c":'100100',"d":'100110',"e":'100010',"f":'110100',"g":'110110',"h":'110010',"i":'010100',"j":'010110',"k":'101000',"l":'111000',"m":'101100',"n":'101110',"o":'101010',"p":'111100',"q":'111110',"r":'111010',"s":'011100',"t":'011110',"u":'101001',"v":'111001',"w":'010111',"x":'010111',"y":'101011',"z":'101011'}
    inputList = plaintext.split(',')
    for word in inputList:
        print words[word]

text = "j,o,s,e"
answer(text)
```

You had a bunch of typos in your `dict`, pay attention to the traceback, it tells you exactly what's wrong. You also never actually called the function you defined. You probably want your `dict` values to be strings as well.

Comment: Have you tested the code? It won't work as the user wants, because when printing `011100` in Python2, you'll got 4672, simply because integers starting with 0 in Python2 are interpreted as octal numbers. A good thing to do is to convert all that values to strings.

Comment: Yes, I commented on that. I'll edit my answer shortly, I'm on mobile and adding the quotes will be a huge pain.